# base query method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Im trying to create a base query that I can then use later to add grouping or filters

simplified example:

```
function baseQuery()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
    return $query;
}

function queryWhere($value)
{
    $query = $this->baseQuery();
    $query->where($value)
    $result = $query->get();

    return $result
}
```

What is the correct way to do this in CodeIgniter?

Comment: i think the better question is - what do you want to achieve here ?

Comment: Any errors except missed semi-colon?

Comment: So i have a lengthy query that has several joins etc and I want to use those queries in other methods but sometimes they query will be grouped, sometimes will have a where etc. So i want a base query and then I can just tag on the additional bits so i dont have to wrtie this long query 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs some dynamic values like table and field names for extending single purpose of query
Take a look on example

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Testing extends CI_Controller {

    public function baseQuery($fields,$tableName)
    {
        $query = $this->db;
        $query->select($fields);
        $query->from($tableName);
        return $query;
    }

    public function queryWhere($whereCondition)
    {
        $query = $this->baseQuery('*','tablename');
        $query->where($whereCondition);
        $result = $query->get();
        return $result;
    }
    public function index() {

        $query = $this->queryWhere("id > 0");
        $data = $query->result_array();
        print_r($data);
    }  

}
```